# How to make a userform release system graphics (.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, datagridview, multithreading

I'm using VS2008 and I've managed to pull together code that I've taught myself (badly) along with stuff I've found on the internet and I've now hit a wall.  I've had a look around and I can't figure out how to get around the problem.

When someone presses a button I thread out to two modules, the first puts a picture box ontop of the datagrid and spins an image whilst it waits for the second thread to save data to Excel.  The problem I get is the error message 'object in use elsewhere' when it gets to the line 'Me.PictureBox4.Image = DirectCast(BM_out.Clone(), System.Drawing.Image)' while running the code.

```
Public MoveByCalc As Double
Public ReturnStack As New System.Collections.Generic.Stack(Of Integer)
Public BM_In As New Bitmap(My.Resources.Fan)
Public Wid As Single = BM_In.Width
Public Hgt As Single = BM_In.Height
Public Cx As Single = Wid / 2
Public Cy As Single = Hgt / 2
Public TimeElapsed As Single = 1
Public EndThread As String = "No"
Public X As Integer
Public BS As New BindingSource
Public AutoNum As Integer
Public CellConnection As New OleDbConnection
Public DB1Connection As New OleDbConnection
Public DB2Connection As New OleDbConnection
Public OldScrollValue As Integer : Public Direction As Integer
Public objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Public objDataSet As New DataSet()
Public objDataAdapterDB1 As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Public objDataSetDB1 As New DataSet()
Public objDataAdapterDB2 As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Public objDataSetDB2 As New DataSet()
Public DBCount As String
Public LoadError As Integer

Public TempString As String
Public DisableSearch As Integer
Public DataGridTop As Double
Public DataGridHeight As Double
Public DataGridBottom As Double
Public DBLoc As Integer
Public ButtonSelectedColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(253, 183, 89)

Public Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    PictureBox4.Visible = True
    PictureBox4.Top = DataGridView1.Top : PictureBox4.Left = DataGridView1.Left
    PictureBox4.Height = DataGridView1.Height : PictureBox4.Width = DataGridView1.Width

    EndThread = "No"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView

    Dim T As Thread
    T = New Thread(AddressOf Me.FanSpin)
    T.Start()
    Dim S As Thread
    S = New Thread(AddressOf Me.SaveData)
    S.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub FanSpin()

    Dim KeepRunning As Boolean = True
    'On Error GoTo EndThread
    While KeepRunning
        TimeElapsed = TimeElapsed + 1

        Dim Corners As Point() = { _
            New Point(0, 0), _
            New Point(Wid, 0), _
            New Point(0, Hgt), _
            New Point(Wid, Hgt)}

        Dim I As Long
        For I = 0 To 3
            Corners(I).X -= Cx
            Corners(I).Y -= Cy
        Next I

        Dim theta As Single = Single.Parse(-TimeElapsed) * PI / 180.0
        Dim X As Single
        Dim Y As Single
        For I = 0 To 3
            X = Corners(I).X
            Y = Corners(I).Y
            Corners(I).X = X * Cos(theta) + Y * Sin(theta)
            Corners(I).Y = -X * Sin(theta) + Y * Cos(theta)
        Next I

        Dim xmin As Single = Corners(0).X
        Dim ymin As Single = Corners(0).Y
        For I = 1 To 3
            If xmin > Corners(I).X Then xmin = Corners(I).X
            If ymin > Corners(I).Y Then ymin = Corners(I).Y
        Next I
        For I = 0 To 3
            Corners(I).X -= xmin
            Corners(I).Y -= ymin
        Next I

        Dim BM_out As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CInt(-2 * xmin), CInt(-2 * ymin))
        Dim gr_out As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BM_out)
        ReDim Preserve Corners(2)

        SyncLock BM_In
            gr_out.DrawImage(BM_In, Corners)
        End SyncLock

        If BM_out IsNot Nothing Then
            SyncLock BM_out
                Me.PictureBox4.Image = DirectCast(BM_out.Clone(), System.Drawing.Image)
            End SyncLock
        End If

        If EndThread = "Yes" Then
            KeepRunning = False
        End If

    End While
    EndThread:

    PictureBox4.Image = Nothing
    If Me.PictureBox4.InvokeRequired Then
        PictureBox4.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf PictureBox4.Hide))
    Else
        Me.PictureBox4.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub DataBindToDataGrid()
    Select Case ReturnStack.Peek()
        Case 1
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSetDB1.Tables(0).DefaultView
        Case 2
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSetDB2.Tables(0).DefaultView
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()

    Dim CallDataBindToDataGrid As New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.DataBindToDataGrid)
    Dim XLApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim XlRange As Excel.Range

    XLApp = New Excel.Application

    Wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Settings.Database3C)

    Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Ws.Activate()

    Ws.Unprotect()

    XlRange = Ws.Range("A5", "V100")
    XlRange.ClearContents()
    XlRange = Ws.Range("A5")

    Dim Count As Integer = 0

    For Count = 0 To 49
        XlRange.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(0).Value
        XlRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(3).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 4).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 5).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(5).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 6).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(6).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 7).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(7).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 8).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(8).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 9).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(9).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 10).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(10).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 11).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(11).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 12).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(12).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 13).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(13).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 14).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(14).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 15).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(15).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 16).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(16).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 17).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(17).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 18).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(18).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 19).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(19).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 20).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(20).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 21).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(21).Value.ToString
        XlRange.Offset(0, 22).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(23).Value.ToString     'DB Log numbers
        XlRange = XlRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Next Count

    XLApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wb.Save()

    Wb.Close()
    Wb = Nothing

    ReturnStack.Push(1)
    If My.Settings.Database1 <> "" Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(CallDataBindToDataGrid)
        Wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Settings.Database1)
        GoTo SaveData
    End If
    ReturnLabel1:
    ReturnStack.Push(2)
    If My.Settings.Database2 <> "" Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(CallDataBindToDataGrid)
        Wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Settings.Database2)
        GoTo SaveData
    End If
    ReturnLabel2:

    SaveData:

    Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Analysis")
    Ws.Activate()
    Ws.Unprotect()
    XlRange = Ws.Range("A10", "AO2009")
    XlRange.ClearContents()
    XlRange = Ws.Range("A10")

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer

    For I = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        If DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(1).Value.ToString <> "" Then
            For J = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                Ws.Cells(I + 10, J + 1) = DataGridView1(J, I).Value.ToString()
            Next
        End If
    Next

    XLApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wb.Save()

    Wb.Close()
    Wb = Nothing

    Select Case ReturnStack.Peek()
        Case 1 : GoTo ReturnLabel1
        Case 2 : GoTo ReturnLabel2
    End Select

    EndSub101:
    XLApp.Quit()
    XLApp = Nothing

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    EndThread = "Yes"

    End Sub
```

I've narrowed the problem down (I think) to the system not releasing the graphics (releasehdc?) when I change the datasource of the datagridview.  I think this is the case as it works when I don't change the datasource and it actually starts working in it's current state but stops halfway through!  I need to change the datasource so I can save different data sets to different Excel files.

I know I shouldn't be calling graphics inside threads and cross threading like this (it's the only way I could get it to work...sort of) but any help someone could provide to get around this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, when your question is about a programming language and/or includes source code, it helps to add a tag for that language. This enables syntax highlighting and formatting, and helps the right people find the question. (I added the [tag:vb.net] tag for you)

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  Bit of a newbie here :)